# How to pronounce A'B'C'?

Tags: word-request, terminology, mathematics

Triangles ABC and A'B'C' are similar.
Given: m' > m.
How to pronounce ' (штрих in Russian)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word that you're looking for is: **prime**.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_(symbol)):

> "The prime symbol ( ′ ), double prime symbol ( ″ ), triple prime
>   symbol ( ‴ ), quadruple prime symbol ( ⁗ ) etc., are used to designate
>   units and for other purposes in mathematics, the sciences, linguistics
>   and music."

See also [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26530/how-is-a-in-mathematics-pronounced), for more examples how to use this word in sentences.

Comment: Following that, I believe ABC’ will also be an acceptable way of saying it.